# How to organize a loop of async.waterfall calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

How to organize a loop of async.waterfall calls **so that every iteration 
starts only after the previous one is fully finished**.

So far I have the following code:

```
var hasMoreData = true;
async.whilst(function () {
  // * has more data?
  return hasMoreData;
},
function processData(callback1) {
  async.waterfall([
    function readDataFromSource(callback2) {
      // * read data
      readData(function readFinished(data, hasMore) {
        // * got data 
        hasMoreData = hasMore;
        callback2(null, data);
      });
    }, 
    function writeDataToDest(data, callback2) {
      // * write data
      writeData(data, function writeFinished() {
        callback2();
      });
    },
  ], function (err) {
    callback1(err);
  });
},
function finished(err) {

});
```

It works like this:

- has more data ? (1)
- read data (1)
- **has more data ? (2)**
- **read data (2)**
- got data (1)
- write data (1)
- ...

**I understand why it works in this order**, and this may be totally correct in some cases. But in my specific case I need to start a new iteration only after the previous one is finished:

- has more data ? (1)
- read data (1)
- got data (1)
- write data (1)
- **has more data ? (2)**
- **read data (2)**
- ...

PS: I can't read all the data into array and then process the array with async.each, for example. Neither I can predict how much data the external source has.

Comment: You've labelled `readData` and `writeData` as "blocking i/o operation", but normally functions that accept completion callbacks are **non-blocking** (asynchronous, usually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `async`, but just looking at the code and description and API docs, it seems like this does what you want, not using `waterfall` at all:

```
var hasMoreData = true;
async.whilst(function () {
  // * has more data?
  return hasMoreData;
},
function processData(callback1) {
  // * read data
  // blocking i/o operation
  readData(function readFinished(data, hasMore) {
    // * got data
    hasMoreData = hasMore;
    // * write data
    // blocking i/o operation
    writeData(data, function writeFinished() {
      callback1();
    });
  });
},
function finished(err) {

});
```

**Live Example** (using shims for `readData` and `writeData`):

```js
// Shims
var datacount = 0;
function readData(callback) {
  // since you said "blocking", busy-wait for a quarter second
  var done = Date.now() + 250;
  while (done > Date.now()) {
  }
  // but calls like this are almost always async, so we'll complete async
  ++datacount;
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(datacount, datacount < 3);
  }, 0);
}
function writeData(data, callback) {
  // since you said "blocking", busy-wait for a quarter second
  var done = Date.now() + 250;
  while (done > Date.now()) {
  }
  // but calls like this are almost always async, so we'll complete async
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback();
  }, 0);
}

// The code
var hasMoreData = true;
async.whilst(function() {
  // * has more data?
  snippet.log("has more data?");
  return hasMoreData;
},
function processData(callback1) {
  // * read data
  snippet.log("read data");
  // blocking i/o operation
  readData(function readFinished(data, hasMore) {
    // * got data
    snippet.log("got data: " + data + " (more? " + hasMore + ")");
    hasMoreData = hasMore;
    // * write data
    snippet.log("write data");
    // blocking i/o operation
    writeData(data, function writeFinished() {
      callback1();
    });
  });
},
function finished(err) {
  snippet.log("finished");
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/1.5.0/async.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like not using waterfall doesn't change anything. The second iteration  starts because of the first one being blocked by readData

Comment: @xtx: That seems to directly contradict [the documentation for `whilst`](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst). Are you absolutely certain it's not observational error?

Comment: @xtx: I've added a live example: The second iteration doesn't start until the first completes.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Looks like the problem is somewhere in my code, indeed. Going to examine it more carefully.